# Подключить clang++ к clion

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion, clang++

Как подключить компилятор clang++ к Clion **на Windows**? Параметром для cmake, как написано в туториале, компилятор не проходит тест. Проблема в том, что в cmake кэше опции компилятора устанавливаются неправильные. Использую MinGW.

Может быть у кого-нибудь получилось?

Comment: это невозможно!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Вышла новая версия CLion, попробуй сейчас